# Xcode 15 Build Issue: Objective-C Module 'AppKit' Error for iOS-Simulator Target

Tags: ios, swift, appkit, swift-package-manager, xcode15

Runnning the following command on the `Package.swift` worked in Xcode 14.x:

> swift build -Xswiftc -warnings-as-errors -Xswiftc "-sdk" -Xswiftc
> "$(xcrun --sdk iphonesimulator --show-sdk-path)" -Xswiftc "-target"
> -Xswiftc "x86_64-apple-ios15.0-simulator"

However, with the Xcode 15+, I'm getting the following error:

> error: could not build Objective-C module 'AppKit'   import AppKit

On the following line:

```
#if canImport(AppKit)
  import AppKit
#elseif canImport(UIKit)
  import UIKit
#endif
```

If I change the code to the following:

```
#if os(macOS)
  import AppKit
#elseif os(iOS)
  import UIKit
#elseif os(tvOS) || os(watchOS)
  import UIKit
#endif
```

I'm still getting an error:

> error: cannot load underlying module for 'UIKit'   import UIKit

**Questions**

1. Why for some reason starting Xcode 15 the build system tries to build `macOS` / `AppKit` target when I'm invoking just the `iOS-Simulator` build
2. Any hints on how to fix the issue?

**Note**

This command works:

> swift build -Xswiftc -warnings-as-errors

This one as well, successfully builds and tests the package:

> swift test

Comment: Along with the usual incremental (and somewhat hidden changes) to the build system, Apple appears to have made an effort to cleanup platform handling in Xcode (probably because they landed `visionOS` into the mix. I don't use the line command much, but I think you should investigate how the project file defines `canImport`. Try creating a new-Xcode15 project, and compare.

Comment: The build problem is reproducible with both `canImport` and with the `if os` statements. However, with `xcodebuild` command, no issues with either one.

Comment: oh sorry, I see what you mean now... I thought I mentioned this before, but I'll assert it now... generally speaking, you can't complete AppKit into iOS-ish environments. Even if it let you before, I think that was improper.

Comment: I'm not trying to do so. Please take a look, how `AppKit` imports are guarded with the if statements.

Comment: okay, I think there could be a more basic problem... if you use *both* code snippets, instead of replacing one with the other, which error do you get? (My guess is the `UIKit` error will happen first.